# How to let the diagram drawed by canvas produce onclick event

Tags: android, canvas, onclick

I have an imageView and I draw the diagram in imageView according to the coordinate array. Every diagram has an onclick event. 
Activity.java

```
package com.example.floorexhibitiontest;
import com.floor.DrawView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
public class HallActivity extends Activity {@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hall);
    }

    float[][][] points = new float[][][] {
        {
            {213,264},
            {247,232},
            {345,338},
            {310,371}
        },
        {
            {171,305},
            {205,272},
            {302,373},
            {267,406}
        },
        {
            {571,320},
            {606,320},
            {606,428},
            {571,428}
        }
    };

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.root);
    final DrawView draw = new DrawView(this,points);
    layout.addView(draw);       
}
```

DrawView.java

```
package com.floor;
import com.example.floorexhibitiontest.R;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Shader.TileMode;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawView extends View{
    private float[][][] points = null;
    DisplayMetrics metric = new DisplayMetrics();

    public DrawView(Context context,float[][][] p) {
        super(context);
        metric = context.getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        points = p;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        float density=metric.density;  

        for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
            Paint p = new Paint();
            p.setAntiAlias(true);
            p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            Path path=new Path();
            path.moveTo(points[i][0][0] / density, points[i][0][1] / density);
            path.lineTo(points[i][1][0] / density, points[i][1][1] / density);
            path.lineTo(points[i][2][0] / density, points[i][2][1] / density);
            path.lineTo(points[i][3][0] / density, points[i][3][1] / density);

            path.close();
            p.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            canvas.drawPath(path, p);
        }
    }
}
```

At present effect：
[image]

1. How to let each rectangular drawed produce their own onclick event?
2. There is an ImageView in Layout file. My purpose is to put the graphics paint on the ImageView. But the result is ImageView can display. The painted graphics can not display. If I hide
   ImageView, the image can display.

Ask everyone’s help. Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try smth like this:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
   if((event.getX(0)>=x_coord) && 
      (event.getY(0)>=y_coord) && 
     ( event.getX(0)<=x_coord + your_rectangle_width) && 
      (event.getY(0)<=y_coord + your_rectangle_heigth))
      {
          //rectangle selected
      }
   return true;
}
```

Or use in onTouch() your actual coordinates from points[] array